# Keep image centered without resize, clip left and right overflow

Tags: html, css

I have an background image that I can set with an img tag or through background-image.  I'd like the image to always stay centered in the browser.  Then when resizing the browser I want the image to stay full size and start hiding the overflow on both the left and the right.  The overflow should get clipped on both sides of the image so the center of the image is always in the center.

Comment: "I want the image to stay full size and start hiding the overflow on both the left and the right." Sounds like all you need is to set the x-axis in `background-position` to be `center`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, may need to change slightly depending on your page layout.

```
.parentElement {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.parentElement img {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 200%;
    max-height: 200%;
    top: -999px;
    right: -999px;
    bottom: -999px;
    left: -999px;
    margin: auto !important;
    width: initial;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/409u4zop/4/

If you want to use background image you back just do

```
background-position: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add background size and position

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```

background-size: cover

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area